# Can Ubuntu be installed on systems without an internet connection?

Tags: installation, internet

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a system without any internet or wireless connections?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/81014/ubuntu-linux-installation-without-internet-connection http://askubuntu.com/questions/343767/how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-without-internet-connection#comment439904_343767

Answer (score 3):

You don't need internet to install any operating system. This is a caprice and can be useful to make some updates for the new system "on the air". But you can make this updates and after the system is installed. So, you don't have nothing to lose.

Answer (score 0):

In case of other Linux distributions like Debian you get a choice to download the file, which includes more than just the basic tools for a PC to run. But in case of Ubuntu you don't have that option. You get only Necessary basic tools, although they give you an option to update on the air during installation (you should be connected to Ethernet/LAN) to download the files.

And yes, Ubuntu doesn't require Internet connection to run the installation.